# Unrecognized url in $.getJSON

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

I have problem encountered in using `$.getJSON` because I always get error "`Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetBranches'`"

Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON('testWS.asmx/GetBranches', function (data, status, xhr) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
```

Here is the code for the `web service`

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<BranchesModel> GetBranches()
{
    return BranchesBLL.Instance.GetBranches();
}
```

What is wrong with my URL? How can I possibly fix  this issue so that I can use $.getJSON function?

Comment: try with small case dataType: 'json'

Comment: One is `GET` other is `POST`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you are missing the below lines in your web config.. 
Because by default GET & POST are disabled by ASP.NET 2.0 and above

so add these lines to your web.config and try...

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For more info..
http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/09/04/FIX-Request-format-is-unrecognized-for-URL-unexpectedly-ending-in.aspx